# Is reinforcement learning suitable for the Dial-a-Ride problem?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

Is reinforcement learning suitable for this problem or will it perform poorly against classical algorithms?

"The Dial-a-Ride Problem (DARP) consists of designing vehicle routes and schedules for n users who specify pickup and delivery requests between origins and destinations. The aim is to plan a set of m minimum cost vehicle routes capable of accommodating as many users as possible, under a set of constraints."

Source: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10479-007-0170-8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little different from your problem but [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8094865) article engaged Reinforcement Learning to improve the level-of-service (LOS) for a shared-taxi system.